# Text gets mangled on scroll

Tags: internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

The text inside of the inner table get mangled when I scroll

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <div style="height : 180px; width : 716px;" id="bulk1" class="scroller"> <!-- Scroll setup here -->

     <table class="teamtable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width : 700px;">

        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Billing</td>
...
```

This issue started showing up when I added to the head

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

[image: Mangled Text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like nothing can be done about it. HTML and CSS don't control anti-aliasing or clipping